# MaterializeCSS - What do the color variables do?

Tags: css, materialize

I might be a bit confused on the purpose of these variables.
I went to a color pallette picket, and it provided an output similar to:

```
$primary-color-dark:   #1976D2
$primary-color:        #2196F3
$primary-color-light:  #BBDEFB
$primary-color-text:   #FFFFFF
$accent-color:         #FF5722
$primary-text-color:   #212121
$secondary-text-color: #757575
$divider-color:        #BDBDBD
```

When I use Material on Angular, I'm aware it automatically applies to `md` components, and not normal HTML so perhaps I am confusing the point of these variables.

How exactly do I apply them?

I've tried `<div class="primary color">` to match the syntax I would to force a color but it doesn't apply the `2196F3` I would thought it would. I've also tried similar to

```
button
   color: $primary-color
```

in the SASS file, but similar results. Am I missing something simple, or so I have to apply it to every element with the color I want

Comment: In preprocessors variables are used in the same way as in any other programming languages. So your SASS example is the exact way of using your color variables. It should work like this, but I guess there is something wrong in your SASS. Have you imported the file that contains all those variables into the file you have your button stylings?

Comment: @JavaEvgen I have imported `materialize/colors` - I think what I'm missing is how to APPLY them, more than set them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variables in your Sass files can be used only in your Sass files. The browser don't read these variables.

When you use preprocessors like this, what you need to do is to compile the .scss files, so they become .css files with the variables being substituted by its values.

For example:

**style.scss**

```
$primary-color: #1976D2;
$primary-color-hover: #1976D7; 

a {
    color: $primary-color;
    &:hover {
        color: $primary-color-hover;
    }
}
```

When you compile the style.scss file it'll become a **style.css** file like this:

```
a {
    color: #1976D2;
}

a:hover {
    color: #1976D7;
}
```

See the [Sass guide](http://sass-lang.com/guide) to understand better.

And to compile it, you can use a task runner, it'll save you a lot of time.

Take a look at [this article about Gulp](https://css-tricks.com/gulp-for-beginners/) and for what it's used for.

Comment: That makes complete sense. I know how pre-processors work so I don't know why I was complicating it in my head. I tested multiple times and sure enough, that's exactly how it works. I don't know why I thought Materialize was magical and would just know 'all buttons are X color. Font on {this} should be {that} color.

Thanks a lot for the simple explanation.